# How can I "go to page" in preview via toolbar?

Tags: pdf, preview

I would like to select the page directly from the window, but it is not accessible :[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control click on the toolbar and add the page control field.

It looks blank and has page for the help text in english.

[image: Page control in the toolbar for Preview]

Then you can type whatever page you wish directly into the toolbar without needing to use the Command-Option-G keyboard shortcut to go to a specific page.